# C#: Efficient algorithm to find greatest m elements in an N x N matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

I would like to know if there's an efficient algorithm to find the greatest m elements in an N x N matrix, with a method header like this:

```
double[] greatestValues(double[][] matrix, int numberOfElements);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you treat the N x N matrix as an array of N x N items you can apply one of the following techniques:

> **Direct application of the quick sort based selection algorithm** The quick
>   sort based selection algorithm can be
>   used to find k smallest or k largest
>   elements. To find k smallest elements
>   find the kth smallest element using
>   the median of medians quick sort based
>   algorithm. After the partition that
>   finds the kth smallest element, all
>   the elements smaller than the kth
>   smaller element will be present left
>   to the kth element and all element
>   larger will be present right to the
>   kth smallest element. Thus all
>   elements from 1st to kth element
>   inclusive constitute the k smallest
>   elements. The time complexity is
>   linear in n, the total number of
>   elements.
>
> **Data structure based solutions** Another simple method is to add each
>   element of the list into an ordered
>   set data structure, such as a heap or
>   self-balancing binary search tree,
>   with at most k elements. Whenever the
>   data structure has more than k
>   elements, we remove the largest
>   element, which can be done in O(log k)
>   time. Each insertion operation also
>   takes O(log k) time, resulting in
>   O(nlog k) time overall.
>
> It is possible to transform the list
>   into a heap in Θ(n) time, and then
>   traverse the heap using a modified
>   Breadth-first search algorithm that
>   places the elements in a Priority
>   Queue (instead of the ordinary queue
>   that is normally used in a BFS), and
>   terminate the scan after traversing
>   exactly k elements. As the queue size
>   remains O(k) throughout the traversal,
>   it would require O(klog k) time to
>   complete, leading to a time bound of
>   O(n + klog k) on this algorithm.

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements).

Comment: +1, great answer. I didn't know about the O(n + klog k) algo -- sounds very cool!